# How to calculate the partial derivative of a function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have such function

```
x*sin(y)*cos(z)
```

-What are the simple ways in R to calculate all possible derivatives of a function. I was able to manually calculate only such

```
x=cos(z)*sin(y)
y=x*cos(y)*cos(z)
z=-x*sin(y)*sin(z)
xx=0
xy=cos(y)*cos(z)
xz=-sin(y)*sin(z)
yx=cos(y)*cos(z)
yy=-x*cos(z)*sin(y)
yz=-x*cos(y)*sin(z)
zx=-sin(y)*sin(z)
zy=-x*cos(y)*sin(z)
zz=-x*cos(z)*sin(y)
```

and is the way  get for each of this derivatives the plot?
Thank you.

Comment: look at [that](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/calculus/vignettes/derivatives.html)

Comment: `pracma::jacobian` gives you the slope in all directions at a given point x0